# AWS: Connect Amplify to custom domain on Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

As per title, for some reason I'm unable to connect the deployed app on Amplify to a custom domain provided on Route 53.

Here's the app deployed with Amplify: https://master.dwog1beoc1uv7.amplifyapp.com/

On Route 53, I created a hosted zone and added a `CNAME` record which should connect the custom domain to the domain where amplify hosts the app:

[image]

I then went to Amplify and added a new domain for the application:

[image]

If I now go back to Route 53, I can see the records have been automatically updated as followed:

[image]

Although everything seem setup properly, the custom domain (http://alessiopetrin.com/) doesn't work just yet.

If I test the record on Route 53, all seem fine:

[image]

I understand I should allow some time for the DNS propagation to take effect (up to 24h for what AWS states), but the time is almost up and I can't see it working, which make me think something is off.

As per second screenshot, I can see on Amplify that is waiting me to add the `CNAME` record in order to activate the domain, so I may think that could be the missing piece; Problem is the record has been assigned automatically already on Route 53, so not really sure if I should add the record somewhere else as well?

Apologise if I'm asking something obvious, and thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The records added by Amplify are correct. I executed dig command on your domain and observed "SERVFAIL" status. This error is due to the mismatch in the name servers.

The following name servers are used currently.

ns1.dynadot.com
ns2.dynadot.com

Ref: https://www.whois.com/whois/alessiopetrin.com

Please set the name servers to the NS record of hosted zone (https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Lj8.png). Refer below docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing

Then, delete the domain from amplify and try re-adding it. It should work.

Comment: That was exactly the case, thank you so much!

Comment: Np, I am glad to know the solution worked.

Comment: I want to do a shoutout to this post cause following the Amplify tutorial guide on AWS did NOT result in things going smoothly and this post led me to checking if my Amplify app's name servers matched my domain name servers.  (They didn't) so Thanks again for your post.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that the require cname ask by aws to generate the SSL is mandatory and should has the following form :
[image: DNS entry]

Comment: Isn't that the same record format as the one I posted in the question? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Lj8.png

Comment: Yes it is....Mmmm. Maybe retry the custom domain configuration from amplify. It's a time consuming process ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I tried many times, but unfortunately that didn't land me far..

Answer (score 0):

An obvious error in Route53 is that Value/Route traffic goes to https://master.dwog1beoc1uv7.amplifyapp.com/. When you add CNAMEs, you don't add the protocol, but only the domain name. It should be master.dwog1beoc1uv7.amplifyapp.com

**EDIT**
There is a problem with the Cloudfront Distribution. I can't tell, if this is because something you did or it is an amplify problem. You need to somehow debug the distribution. Go to Cloudfront service in AWS console and locate your distribution. Some things to check:

[image: General Settings]

- Alternate domain is correct (your custom domain)
- SSL certificate is correct

Go to behaviors tab and click edit:

[image: Behavior]

- An S3 bucket with your code should be used as an origin
- There should be no caching on Headers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! After I added the domain on Amplify though, the Route 53 records have been updated automatically to be as followed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Lj8.png

Comment: There is a problem with your cloudfront distribution (dmr4lhcn6haet.cloudfront.net). Have you created this yourself or did amplify did it for you?

Comment: It was generated automatically by Amplify, soon after I added a new domain on the Amplify service - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyfgZ.png, that was done on the 'SSL creation' step